# How to share data segment to procedure assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, masm32

I am trying to concat three strings:

```
data segment public
    a db 'hei, $'
    alen equ $-a-1
    b db 'how are you $'
    blen equ $-b-1
    c db 'Michael ?$'
    clen equ $-c-1

    rez db alen+blen+clen+1 dup(?) ; adding one, for the $
data ends
```

This is my data segment. I am trying to get this in the rez variable: **hei, how are you Michael ?**
I can make this with a single assembly file, looping using the lenghts and creating the rez string.

My problem is that I'm trying to do this using a procedure. First, I've tried copying the offsets of the variables into the registers (ax, bx, cx, dx, si, di), but ... once I got to the procedure, to code it, I realized that all my registers are used, and I can't do anything with the registers.

As you can see the data segment is public, and I guess it should be seen by the procedure also, but it's not ...

**File1:**

```
assume cs:code, ds:data

data segment public
    a db 'hei, $'
    alen equ $-a-1
    b db 'how are $'
    blen equ $-b-1
    c db 'Michael ?$'
    clen equ $-c-1

    rez db alen+blen+clen+1 dup(?) ; adding one, for the $
data ends
extrn add_to_result:proc
code segment
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    ; save the offsets

    ; do the math, get the rez
    call add_to_result

    ; show result
    mov ax, 0

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, rez

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

**File2 - Procedure**

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment

data ends

code segment public
public add_to_result
add_to_result:
    ; do the math

code ends
end
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**I've tried copying the offsets of the variables into the registers**

Why don't you place the offsets and the lengths on the stack? This will leave all the registers available to your procedure.

**As you can see the data segment is public, and I guess it should be seen by the procedure also, but it's not ...**

Without the rest of the program this is somewhat hard to understand.

Comment: added the source code. I haven't made any program using the stack, I am a beginner. But, I think that's the solution that I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to change `mov ax, data` into `mov ax,@data` ?

Comment: Don't think so. If you can explain why ... ?

Comment: Many assemblers require this syntax when addressing program segments.

Comment: Also try removing `data segment ... data ends` from file2.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified clearly what you want your procedure to do.

One possibility is that you can implement something similar to the C `strcat` function. For that you would pass in 2 arguments and invoke your procedure 3 times to glue the 3 pieces together. For efficiency, the function could return the a pointer to the end of the string. You would do: `cat(cat(cat(rez, a), b), c)`.

To pass in the arguments you can use your own convention, such as `ax` for first argument, `dx` for second. For the return value you can then reuse `ax` again, which will make your nesting easy:

```
mov ax, offset rez
mov dx, offset a
call cat
mov dx, offset b
call cat
mov dx, offset c
call cat
```

Your `cat` function should copy characters from memory at `dx` into memory at `ax` until it hits the terminating `$`, whose address it should then return in `ax`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass parameters to a far function is of course registers, but the most efficient and usual way is using stack. (**And don't forget that there are two files and you are using static data(data segment), so you have to pass data segment address, too.**

so that would be sth like this in the main method:

```
push ds
mov ax, offset a
push ax
mov ax, offset b
push ax
mov ax, offset c
push ax
call cat
```

And in the cat proc, pop the values in the reverse order. and don't forget to pop ds too.